# What's the best way to have dynamic boards for different difficulties in android?

Tags: android, dynamic-ui

I'm having null pointer exception in the following code. I'm new to android. Please help me in removing that and also suggest a better way to have different size board for various difficulty level in a game.

```
package com.example.prashant.minesweeper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int prev_board = 3;
    private final static int Easy_Board = 10;
    private final static int Medium_Board = 20;
    private final static int Hard_Board = 40;

    MyButton buttons[][];
    LinearLayout rows[];
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    TextView tv1,tv2;

    public void setLayout(int n) {
        if(prev_board==n) {
            resetBoard();
            return;
        }
        prev_board = n;
        mainLayout.removeAllViews();

        rows = new LinearLayout[n+1];
        buttons = new MyButton[n][n];

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams row_param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,2);
        rows[0].setLayoutParams(row_param);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1);
        tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv1.setLayoutParams(param);
        tv1.setText("SCORE : ");
        tv2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv2.setLayoutParams(param);
        tv2.setText("0 ");
        rows[0].addView(tv1);
        rows[0].addView(tv2);
        mainLayout.addView(rows[0]);

        row_param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,1);
        param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1);
        for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++){
            rows[i].setLayoutParams(row_param);
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){

                buttons[i-1][j].setLayoutParams(param);
                rows[i].addView(buttons[i-1][j]);
            }
            mainLayout.addView(rows[i]);
        }
    }

    public void resetBoard() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        setLayout(Easy_Board);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.Easy   : setLayout(Easy_Board); break;
            case R.id.Medium : setLayout(Medium_Board); break;
            case R.id.Hard   : setLayout(Hard_Board); break;
            case R.id.NewGame: resetBoard(); break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is my logcat

```
01-30 13:14:12.938 18751-18751/com.example.prashant.minesweeper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prashant.minesweeper/com.example.prashant.minesweeper.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.prashant.minesweeper.MainActivity.setLayout(MainActivity.java:38)
        at com.example.prashant.minesweeper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your **LogCat** or stack Trace

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: `rows = new LinearLayout[n+1];` - That line only initializes the array. It doesn't instantiate each of the `n+1` `LinearLayout`s, so `rows[0].setLayoutParams(row_param)` is throwing the NPE. You need to initialize each item in the array. Same for your `MyButton` array.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks Bro !!!